# Salesforce SDK screen freeze on iOS 8.4.1

Tags: ios, sdk, salesforce

I am using Salesforce iOS sdk 3.0.0 in my application, The problem what happens on iOS 8.4.1 is when I login to app using Salesforce credentials, the Salesforce login screen app freezes on Rootviewcontroller.

**Rootviewcontroller**  is not clickable on iOS version 8.4.1.

*It works fine on earlier version of iOS.*